# bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool) crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, webview

I'm seeing some crashes in my App crash tracking tool. Basically I have a tabBarController, one of the tabs has an embedded UIWebView, another tab has a controller with a UITableView. So what happens is that when user goes to the WebView first, and it starts loading, after a few seconds they go to the tableView controller, the crash randomly happens.

Judged by the timing I saw in crash log, it seems that the webView is about to finish loading when the user taps the UITableView tab, so I inserted a code into the didFinishLoading. This way I can reliably reproduce the crash. The code looks like this:

The webViewController:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [tabBarController gotoTableViewController];
}
```

The tableViewController:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Here is the crash:

```
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x1700113d0: Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug. Crashing now...
```

I don't know what I can do about it, it seems both the webView and tableView are locking the mainThread? Is there a way to "unload" the webView loading from main thread? I've tried stopLoading, not working...

Comment: did you use any [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop ] ?

Comment: This crash is due to your code is running in background thread so load your code in main thread

Comment: try this code dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{//call you method here});

Comment: @KKRocks Sorry guys, I missed this part. I did have some code which runs NSRunLoop to parse a bundled file. It is running on mainThread. I'll investigate. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Found it. It was indeed caused by the file parsing on mainThread. My file parsing is utilising NSRunLoop to parse a XML file. However the file is meant to be used as a cached values and needed to be parsed synchronously, so I put it on mainThread. I tried to put it onto a background thread and use `dispatch_sync`, the crash's still there. So I tried `dispatch_async` with a `dispatch_semaphore_t`, the crash was gone!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I also had an `NSRunLoop` that could potentially ran while the WebView was fetching the data.
Removing the NSRunLoop the problem is now fixed, but I don't understand why the problem happens in first place.
@KKRocks could you elaborate a bit why the NSRunLoop should cause the WebView to run in background?